# Startup time from systemd-analyze blame does not add up

Tags: startup, ubuntu-mate

When you add up the values, it's way more than 51 seconds.?

(Partial list of services.)

```
Startup finished in 6.983s (kernel) + 44.191s (userspace) = 51.174s
graphical.target reached after 42.255s in userspace
andy@7_~/Downloads$ systemd-analyze blame
         21.614s systemd-journal-flush.service
         21.044s dev-sda1.device
         18.941s ufw.service
         18.410s configure-printer@usb-002-003.service
         16.334s keyboard-setup.service
         11.486s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         11.362s configure-printer@usb-002-004.service
         10.167s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
         10.101s systemd-sysctl.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd tries to [parallelize](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/blame-game.html) startup — search for parallel.

This means that if unit A takes 10 secs and B 12 secs the "total" could be anything from 12 to 22 secs.